# Is there a way to use Kubernetes Container environment variables in the Log4Net.config?

Tags: kubernetes, log4net

I am trying to find out if I can use a container environment variable inside the Log4Net.config to separate our logs environment, for easier reading on Kibana.

My idea was to set a variable in the container that appends into the ApplicationName value of our RabbitMqAppender.

I probably could use a configMap for the Log4Net.config, but I don't think it would be viable for the number of applications we have running.

Answer (score 0):

A typical pattern here is to use a [log processor sidecar](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-sidecar-container-with-the-logging-agent). Some of the ones you can use are:

- [Fluent-bit](https://fluentbit.io/)
- [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/)
- [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)
- [logspout](https://github.com/gliderlabs/logspout)
- [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat)

For any logger about you can use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-a-logging-agent) for different types of applications.

Another pattern is to use any of the above tools deployed as [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) where each daemon in the Kubernetes picks everything up from a mountPath and forwards it to an ElasticSearch instance. For example, forwards everything under `/var/log/containers/*.log`

In all examples, it's assumed that your containers are logging to `stdout/stderr`.